# the addEntry method in LinkedHashMap in java

Tags: java

Recently I read the source code of `LinkedHashmap` in java，I know that the linked hashmap use doubly link to restore entry. When `addEntry`，it will remove the eldest key of the list, but when I read the code, I have some problem

```
426    addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
427        super.addEntry(hash, key, value, bucketIndex);
428
429        // Remove eldest entry if instructed
430        Entry<K,V> eldest = header.after;
431        if (removeEldestEntry(eldest)) {
432            removeEntryForKey(eldest.key);
433        }
434    }
```

in line 430，`eldest = header.after`，but I think the end of the list is not `header.after`, because `header.after` is the second entry.

Comment: can you also include the code for `removeEldestEntry` ?

Answer (score 2):

The code for `LinkedHashMap` has changed over time, and it's completely different code for android, so I'm not exactly sure which version that is. However, in my view it makes sense to have "dummy" nodes before the first node and after the last node (so that even an empty `LinkedHashMap` has 2 nodes). This way you can remove a node `X` from the map by getting the nodes before and after `X`:

```
X.before -> X -> X.after
```

and setting the new node following `X.before` to be `X.after` and the new node coming before `X.after` to be `X.before`.

```
X.before ------> X.after     (X has gone.)
```

The code for this can simply be:

```
X.before.after = X.after;
X.after.before = X.before;
```

If you don't have dummy nodes, either or both of `X.before` or `X.after` could be `null`, so it makes this process slightly more awkward to code.

I have seen versions of `LinkedHashMap` that use these 2 extra nodes, and other versions that don't. In the [version you're looking at](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mduigou/althashing7/8/webrev/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java.sdiff.html), the first and last "dummy" nodes (called `header`) are actually the same object reused.

Comment: I‘m sorry,I think what you said has not linked to my quesqion.

Comment: @ManZhang Ok, well you need to clarify your question. The current version of `LinkedHashMap` doesn't include that code at all. Can you include the link to the place you found it?

Comment: Also, my answer *does* answer your question. You've said that `header.after` is the second eldest entry, but it isn't - it's the first. This is because `header` is just a "dummy" entry to start the chain. The eldest "real" entry in the map is `header.after`.

Comment: thank you,in linkedhashmap the first element is the prev of header,and the  eledest is the next of header.